# Negative Bounds for Slice Operator

Tags: python, slice

I am new to python and one of the things every newbie do come across is the slice operator. I have a list:

```
li=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

As per my understanding calling `li[:-1]` is same as calling `li[0:-1]` and it is but when using it with a negative steps things do not work exactly as I thought they would. So getting to my question why the result of

```
print(li[:-3:-2]) # is 7
```

but the result of

```
print(li[0:-3:-2]) # is []
```

Looking forward to some explanation of how the negative step is being treated in this scenario.

Comment: I have no idea what the mechanics of this are - but if you need a workaround, doing `li[:-3][::-2]` instead of `li[:-3:-2]` produces the (expected) `[4, 2]`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I am more interested in finding a proper explanation for this rather than a workaround :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is that missing (or None) start value is not always automatically set to 0. Please read the note 5 in [sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) for `s[i:j:k]`

> If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end
>   depends on the sign of k)

To simplify the situation, consider negative step -1 instead of -2. Step -1 is often used to reverse a list.

```
>>> print(li[None:-3:-1])
[7, 6]
>>> print(li[0:-3:-1])
[]
```

The first example shows, what are the real "end values" for the slice.

Answer (score 2):

So, your list is `li=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

First, understand what exactly happens in slicing.

**Slicing can't be done in backward direction without using step**.

Take an example, we wan't to print `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`, we can't do this using `li[-1:0]`. because, slicing can't go backward as stated (we can't go backwards from index -1 to 0), and will return empty list `[]`.(We have to do this using `li[-1:0:-1]`)

So what happens here is:

you have a list `li[x:y]`, using a negative step will swap the indexes as `li[y:x]`.(Once swapping of indexes is done, you should consider it as a positive step) and then print out your output w.r.t. your provided step(only the magnitude).

Now, all that I mentioned above might seem useless, but it would help you understand next part.

So, coming to your question, when you write `li[0:-3:-2]`, first,indexes are swapped. So, it is same as `li[-3:0:2]`. and as I have stated above, we can't go backwards (index `-3` to `0`) without using a negative step, so it returns the empty list.

but, when you give input as `li[:-3:-2]`, It swaps the indexes and becomes `li[-3::2]` and we now easily know what will be the output (`[7]`).

So, don't consider the blank space in `[:-3:-2]` as `0` but as left end.(for better understanding)

Hope this helped.